# Using Journey Builder to update campaign member for both leads and contacts

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, automationstudio, campaign-member

We have a journey which both contacts and leads are injected into it. We would like to add both of those to a SF campaign without using using multiple decision splits and update campaign member activities for lead path and contact path. This requirement is due to many SF campaign member updates we should preform throughout the journey.

Using AMPscript we're able to update/create a campaign member record using the 'LeadOrContactId' regardless if it is a contact or lead being processed.  We thought maybe to use the same field with the Object Activity but found it has the same functionality when selecting campaign member object and no option to select the 'LeadOrContactId' field.

**Did anyone manage to achieve this in Journey Builder without building a custom activity OR inserting AMPscript snippets to send activities?**

Appreciate your help,

Barak